# Yii: two ajax validates in one controller

Tags: php, yii

I have 1 form, 2 models. I trying use ajax validation for each of it.
It work separately but together nothing work..
**Form:**

```
<?php $activeform = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'registration-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'validateOnChange' => true,
        ),
));
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
$form = new ClassModel1_Form1;
$profile = new ClassModel2_Form1;

if ( isset($_POST['ajax'])  &&  $_POST['ajax'] === 'registration-form'  &&  isset($_POST[CHtml::modelName($form)]) ) {
    echo CActiveForm::validate($form);  
    Yii::app()->end();
}

if ( isset($_POST['ajax'])  &&  $_POST['ajax'] === 'registration-form'  &&  isset($_POST[CHtml::modelName($profile)]) ) {
    echo CActiveForm::validate($profile);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are terminating execution after first check.

You can pass array of models for `CActiveForm::validate([$form, $profile])`